# Read Lines, Change & Delete Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, edit

I have a file that I would like to manipulate in Ruby. I am sure it should be easy but could not find it as I am a newbie. At the lines I have some datas like;

```
Bassmaster Boats Inc#Bassmaster Boats Inc                    
Basstream#Basstream                    
Bat Inflatable Boats#Bat Inflatable Boats                    
Bavaria Motoryachts#Bavaria Motoryachts                    
Bavaria Sailing Yachts#Bavaria Sailing Yachts                    
Bay Craft Inc#Bay Craft Inc                    
Bay Hawk Industries Inc#Bay Hawk Industries Inc                    
Bay Quest#Bay Quest                    
Bay Warrior Boats#Bay Warrior Boats                    
Bay Water Boats#Bay Water Boats                    
Bayfield Boat Yard Ltd#Bayfield Boat Yard Ltd                    
Bayliner Marine Corp#Bayliner Marine Corp                    
Baymaster Boats Inc#Baymaster Boats Inc                    
Baymaster by Dargel#Baymaster by Dargel                    
Bayon#Bayon                    
Bayrunner#Bayrunner
```

What I would like to do is to find the spaces - if any - between words and puts `+` and delete whatever it has after `#` sign. So it should look like ;

```
Bassmaster+Boats+Inc             
Basstream
Bat+Inflatable+Boats
Bavaria+Motoryachts
Bavaria+Sailing+Yachts
.....
.....
.....
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Regular Expression

I suggest you to use [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to find matches.

1. String after # sign inclusively
   `#.*`
2. Spaces
    OR `\s` (Which matches tab character also)

## Substitute matches with Ruby

You can substitute matched string with [`gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html#method-i-gsub-21).

`s.gsub!(/#.*/, '').gsub!(/ /, '+')`

Answer (score 1):

Do as below :

```
File.open("another/file", "w") do |file|
  File.foreach("filename") do |line|
    line[/(#.*)/] = ""
    file.puts line.gsub(\s+\, "+")
  end
end
```